# Autofill to a specific date

Tags: vba, date, autofill

I am working with date data and want to autofill to a specific date.  The specific date will be stored as value `X`. `X` is the last value in column `A`

I've looked at some other posts here on StackOverflow, but the issue I keep running into is setting my final "value".  My final value will not be a number, but a date to stop at.

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form Date 2")
    'Select this workbook

    Dim X as Date 
    'I am not sure what I need to Dim this as

    Range("B2").Value = Range("A2").Value
    'B2 is the value I want to autofill down with

    X = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
    'X will be the last value in column A

    Range("B2").Autofill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & X), Type:=xlFillSeries
    'Not sure what to set my Type as

    End With
```

So the final result would be, Column `B` would obtain all dates from `A1` to last value in `A` `(02/04/2018-05/06/2018)`.  Format should be dd/mm/yyyy.

In Column `A` I have a whole bunch of dates, but some are missing, so I am grabbing all the missing ones as well.

With the picture below I have the `Dates` column.  I want VBA to spit out the `All Dates` column.  So The code will copy and paste `A2` over to `B2` and then autofill until the last value in column `A`(not row).  So in this example `All Dates` should continue down until value/date `01/06/2018`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want to see the dates ? And what error you are facing ?

Comment: Okay, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
'Select this workbook

Dim X As Integer
'I am not sure what I need to Dim this as

.Range("B2").Value = .Range("A2").Value
'B2 is the value I want to autofill down with

X = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'X will be the last value in column A

.Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B2:B" & X), Type:=xlFillDefault
'Not sure what to set my Type as

End With
```

---

Updated Code to fill till the date on the last cell of Column A:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
'Select this workbook

Dim X As Integer
'I am not sure what I need to Dim this as

.Range("B2").Value = .Range("A2").Value
'B2 is the value I want to autofill down with

X = .Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value - .Range("B2").Value
'X will be the last value in column A


.Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B2:B" & X + 2), Type:=xlFillDefault
'Not sure what to set my Type as

End With
```

Comment: @Mikku could you please explain the `+2`?

Comment: Yes we are saying B2:B , that's why we have to add 2. Actually the X now getting calculated is the difference of 2 dates and independent of the row structure.

Comment: But if you took away the `-.Range("B2").Value`.  Would you need the `+2` anymore?

Comment: You can try. Change the B2 to B1. It actually depends on the values we are getting. Try going through the code using `F8`. And verify values at each step. That will make things clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine :

```
Sub test()

Dim X As Integer

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = Range("A2").Value
'B2 is the value I want to autofill down with

X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'X will be the last value in column A

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & X), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

You're welcome :)